# Blackberry fieldmanager issues

Tags: blackberry

I am building a blackberry app for BB Curve.I have a verticalfieldmanager where i am adding a Button,i set its extent as 320*22.I have a horizontalfieldmanager where i am adding two editfield and its extent is 296*22.Finally i am adding both these manager into another verticalfieldmanager whose extent i have set as 320*240.i use setBackgroundBitmap(Background bg) to set the background image.But when i set the extent of the main verticalfieldmanager,only the background image is set,but the other two managers where i have added editfield and button are not visible.But when i dont set the extent of the main vertical manager,than the editfield and button are added to the screen,but the background image is not added.So where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Would you be able to post some of the relevant code for us to take a look at? Also, look at the console and make sure you don't see any messages that say "insufficient space to layout field" or something similar to that.

Comment: @jprofitt Thank you sir for replying.BTW I do see this message at the console "insufficient space to layout field".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're going to have to play with your extents to make sure that you given the child Managers enough space to layout the Fields. In your `sublayout(int width, int height)` of the Managers, check what dimensions are getting passed to it. If they are less than the space it needs to layout, it won't be able to display its Fields.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer.My sublayout is like this

Comment: HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(style) {
             protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
                   sublayout(wd, ht);
                    setExtent(wd, ht);
             }
             public void paint(Graphics g) {
                 if(color!=0)
                    g.setBackgroundColor(color);
                    g.clear();
                    invalidate();
                    super.paint(g);
            }
           
           };

Comment: so when i use super.sublayout fields are displayed but i get the warning,but when i use only the sublayout i don't get any warning but the fields are also not displayed

Comment: I would call `super.sublayout(width, height)` rather than `super.sublayout(wd, ht)` that way it can take the space it needs and then you can change its size

Comment: Thank again sir,btw can we add background image to a mainscreen?i am doing it in this way

Comment: Bitmap bitmapbg=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("bg.png");
bg=BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bitmapbg);

Comment: but the image is not placed at background

Comment: There are problems setting the background on a MainScreen sometimes. Best solution is to add a VerticalFieldManager that you put everything into, and set the background on that

Comment: Thank you sir for your valuable reply,bt when i am adding it from a vertical manager,my fields are getting overlayed by the background image.Background image is placed top of the field,i want the fields to be on top of the image

Comment: Are you adding the fields to that VFM and not the main manager?

Comment: Yes i am adding the image button on that VFM which i then add to the main manager